# What are the steps to do after checking out a Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I usually work with .NET WinForms but now have to work on some Java apps that other team members have written. They have a bunch of POM.XML files so I know it is running bu Maven but not familiar with Maven, so here are the steps I have done so far:

- Installed some Subversion plugins in EClipse and checked out their project.
- There was no small "M" icon next to those projects, so I did a right click and there was some command like Convert to Maven or something like that which I selected and now they are Mavenized ! I guess
- But there are many compile errors , what is the step to fix them? maybe I haven't even compiled the projects yet? what is the order of steps I should take after this point?  I have seen some "mvn clean install" coomands fold run but like I said not sure what is next? 
  So far I have checked out the projects into eclipse and have right cliecked and said convert to maven.

Comment: First test those things on command line and not in IDE..just simply mvn clean package ...

Comment: mvn clean package or mvn clean install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. check out the project
2. On the command line do `mvn clean install` at the root level (the first level that contains a pom).  This will perform the build, which includes downloading all of the libraries.
3. `Import Existing Maven Project` in eclipse.  This will be safer than importing the project and then trying to convert to eclipse
4. Develop (yeah, I know this SHOULD be `...`)
5. Profit!

In order for this to work, you should at least have the m2e plugin for eclipse.  I think it's standard in the Java EE version of eclipse.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just if you have some time, couple you please explain a little more number three: Import Existing Maven project. 
So I don't need mvn clean package?  just install?

Comment: performing an install will automatically perform the package step.  `Import Existing Maven Project` is an option when you right-click in the Projects area and select `Import` if you have m2e installed.  It will take care of setting up the dependencies in eclipse to point to the maven managed dependencies in your local repository and adding them to the build classpath.

Comment: Also, ask the java team if they use a local repository mirror for third party libraries.  If so, they should be able to provide a settings.xml file (or sample) that would go in %home%\.m2\ on your box and allow you to download any missing dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Select the project or `pom.xml` (the one in the root, if there are several), right click -> `Run As...` -> `Maven install`

Maven will then try to compile the project. Usually, this happens in the background but when something goes wrong, the error messages in Eclipse aren't exactly helpful.

When you run Maven in the console, it will print a meaningful error message. Most likely, it couldn't download a dependency.

Comment: so a "run as maven install" on the root and everything is done? :) hopefully if it gives no error.

Comment: I hope it gives an error but one that tells you what is wrong :-)